# Show that φ is one-to-one and onto

Tags: abstract-algebra

Define a map φ from a binary structure ⟨ℚ,*⟩ onto the binary structure ⟨ℚ,⋅⟩ by φ(x)=x+1.

(a) Show that φ is one-to-one and onto

(b) Give the precise definition of * such that φ is an isomorphism.

(c) Is ⟨ℚ,*⟩ a group? Why?

For part b i have: < Q, ∗ > onto < Q, • > Using the fact that φ −1 must also be an isomorphism, we must have m∗n = φ −1 (m+1)∗φ −1 (n+1) = φ −1 ((m+1)•(n+1)) = φ −1 (mn+m+n+1) = mn+m+n. The identity element is φ −1 (1) = 0.

Can someone help me with part a and c?

Comment: Part b is fine. The map is bijective because there is an inverse, namely the function that maps $x$ to $x-1$. For part c you need to check the remaining group axioms, namely associativity and existence of an inverse. Begin by writing down what these axioms mean in terms of the operation $*$.

Comment: I know i need to prove these: Closure
For all a, b in G, the result of the operation, a • b, is also in G.b[›]
Associativity
For all a, b and c in G, (a • b) • c = a • (b • c).
Identity element
There exists an element e in G such that, for every element a in G, the equation e • a = a • e = a holds. Such an element is unique (see below), and thus one speaks of the identity element.
Inverse element
For each a in G, there exists an element b in G, commonly denoted a−1 (or −a, if the operation is denoted "+"), such that a • b = b • a = e, where e is the identity element. But how shld i?